# Linking to site descriptions and help menus

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Can we have a way to see the information and help menu for each SE site? On my device, site names get cut off. Either displaying them in the app or opening them in the browser. That will let users see site descriptions and help menus. The site name in the header can be a link to a menu with the site information, and to the site's help menu from there.

[image: MSE header in the app, the title of the site can be a button]