# In the Stack Exchange Android app, where can I see the description, scope and guidelines for each Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, android-app, scope, rules, guidelines

I posted on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and someone suggested I post on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) instead. I wanted to look up the scope and guidelines for each of the two sites, but in the Android app I could not find them.

Comment: If you look at the usage for the [tag:android-app] tag, you'll notice the following: "NOTE: THE APP IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED." Don't use the app.

Comment: The mobile apps (both of which have been delisted from the stores) don't offer direct access to the Help Center. You have to use your phone's browser.

Comment: I think y’all are too gung-ho about trying to close a post about the app; OP is asking whether an existing feature exists, not about a bug or new feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to site descriptions and help menus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317798/linking-to-site-descriptions-and-help-menus) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221303/android-app-needs-help-and-new-user-guidance - Please note that on MSE a "duplicate" doesn't require an answer, only that an answer to this question would correctly go on that prior question.